# Who is the author of Targum Sheini on Megillas Esther?

Tags: megillat-esther, targumin

Who is the author of Targum Sheini on Megillas Esther? When did he live?

I've checked several Megillas that have Targum Sheini printed in it and none of them have any details. If anyone can find me who the author is, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows, similar to who wrote Targum "Yonasan" or Targum Yerushalmi on Chumash. Who wrote Targum Rishon on Esther?

Comment: it’s written that no one knows.   The thing is that it includes some mid rash that we don’t have so it’s from someone earlier